# 5 Different Fedora server categories

Tags: linux, fedora

Probably a little naughty of me asking this on here, but I've tried and I've Googled and I've asked but I cant find an answer. One of the questions in an assignment on Linux reads as follows *"There are several server categories in Fedora. **List the names of five server 
categories."***

If anyone could give me a good link or a bit of help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you might be talking about "groups" and not "categories". If you run the yumex package management GUI, you'll find that if you sort by "Groups" under the "Servers" group you'll find things like:

"Directory Server"
"DNS Name Server"
"FTP Server"
"Mail Server"
"Basic Web Server"